# Add new button to WP backend menu

Tags: add-submenu-page

I can add a new link under the dashboard menu in the backend of WP

```
function new_link_display() {
    echo "Echo html code for the page";
}

function new_link_page() {
    if (function_exists('add_submenu_page') )
        add_submenu_page('index.php', __('New Like Label'), __('New Link Label'), 'manage_options', 'new-link-display', 'new_link_display');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'new_link_page');
```

How do I add a new button below the Settings button. I don't want it with in the Settings menu but a separate button below it.